# Update user email address in Active Directory using C#

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, active-directory

I'm trying to update the email address for a user in Active Directory using the following code. It is executed successfully but the email address in Active Directory doesn't change.

How can I solve that ?

```
try
{
      using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "yurs.yucc"))
      {
          if (context.ValidateCredentials(username, password))
          {
               UserPrincipal usrPrincipal = new UserPrincipal(context);
               usrPrincipal.EmailAddress = "raedsaleh11@gmail.com";                       
          }
      }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // TODO: log exception
}
```

Comment: Though not an answer to your question but you should not use an empty catch block the exception will get suppressed. Its not a good practice to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to **save** your user principal once it's updated....

```
try
{
    using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "yurs.yucc"))
    {
       if (context.ValidateCredentials(username, password))
       {
          // find the user specified by "username"
          UserPrincipal usrPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, username);

          if(usrPrincipal != null)
          {
              // if found, update e-mail address 
              usrPrincipal.EmailAddress = "raedsaleh11@gmail.com";

              // call .Save() to persist your changes! 
              usrPrincipal.Save();
          }
       }
   }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   // TODO: log exception
}
```

Comment: I tried to save but I face the following exception : SamAccountName or Name must be assigned to a newly-created Principal object in this store prior to saving.

Comment: @RaedAlsaleh: well, in your code, you're creating a **new** user - is that what you want? I expected that you want to **retrieve** an existing user and update it? If you do create a **new user**, then yes, the `samAccountName` is a mandatory field **and must be set** before saving.

Comment: @RaedAlsaleh: so you must **first find the user!** - your code currently just creates an empty, new user. See my response - I'm using  `username` to find that user